# Trying to test re_path regular expressions in django

Tags: python, django, regex

I am trying to write a test for a `re_path` url and I cannot figure it out. Below is my code so far.  Please forgive the Puserid and Pcomment_comment_of_the_day.  I did not know how escape the less than symbol.

`urls.py` file:

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'trophy/(?P<userid>\w+)/(?P<comment_of_the_day>\w+)/$', views.commentoftheday, name='commentoftheday'),
]
```

`tests.py` file:

```py
from django.test import TestCase, Client
from django.urls import reverse

class helpme(TestCase):
    def test1(self):
        response = self.client.get(reverse("commentoftheday"), kwargs={'userid':'bleh'})
        response.status_code
```